# Can we show a modern Calendar view for our Event list inside our modern communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-pages, events

We have created a modern communication site, which comes with a Event list, as follow:-

[image]

now we are trying to show a modern Calendar view inside our modern page for this Event List, but we only got those 2 view options (Filmstrip & Compact):-

[image]

now the workaround we found is that we can Embed the classic url inside the modern page, but it did not look very nice specifically there will be many free space on top of the calendar, as follow:-

[image]

so how we can show a modern calendar view for our Event list inside a modern page?

Thanks